# Unable to create Dynamic Short link with React-native-firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

I'm catching an error with code: "links/failure"

```
const link = new firebase.links.DynamicLink(
      "LINK",
      "firebaseDomainLink"
    ).android
      .setPackageName("packagename")
      .ios.setBundleId("bundleID");
    firebase
      .links()
      .createShortDynamicLink(link, 'UNGUESSABLE')
      .then(url => {
        console.log(url)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.warn(err);
      });
```

However when using "createDynamicLink" I am able to get the long dynamic link as the return.

Tested with Android Platform

[Picture of Yellow error box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TUwz.png)